# Can continuity always be shown by using ε-δ?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, continuity

When we learn calculus we usually:
1. Prove that polynomials, the exponential functions, the logarithmic functions, the trigonometric functions, the inverse trigonometric functions are continuous on its domain.
2. Prove that continuity of any two functions at a point will be preserved, in the resultant function, after taking finitely many times of the four arithmetic operations and composition.
∴  Elementary functions are continuous on its domain.

Question:
For every elementary function $f$, and every point $p$ in the domain of $f$, and every $\epsilon > 0$,
can we **always** find a $\delta > 0$ explicitly as a [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) (including "the maximum function") in terms of $f$, $p$ and $\epsilon$ such that $| x - p | < δ \implies | f(x) - f(p) | < ε$ ?
(In other words, can we always construct at least one valid $\epsilon-\delta$ style argument showing $f$ satisfies the definition of being continuous at $p$?)

After all, elementary functions are infinitely many, but human beings only have finite amount and time.

At the moment the definition of "elementary functions" follows this webpage:
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Elementary_functions

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I suspect it will be more appropriate at math.stackexchange. (I'm not voting to close, since it's possible there are some subtleties I'm not seeing at the moment.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for understanding the meaning of the question we i am asking. :-)

Comment: Just to clarify: the downvote and closure vote (not mine) are re: this question's appropriateness *for this site*, not its inherent value. I think it would be much better received at MSE (although I think you should put some thought into what you mean by "closed form"). Note to others that the OP's [earlier question on similar lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835433/can-we-always-show-the-continuity-of-f-at-p-by-using-epsilon-delta) isn't quite the same as this one.

Comment: It seems like this question is a bit contentious. It might be helpful if those in favor of it were to say a bit about why it's appropriate here ...

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want when you ask for a “closed-form expression... in terms of $f$”?

Comment: Isn't the answer 'obviously yes', because the proofs of continuity of products/compositions/linear-combinations each give closed-form bounds, and composing those closed-form bounds appropriately gives the closed-form bound for the elementary function in question?

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher : I don't think it's quite that simple. In many cases the natural thing to try is to find something like the inverse function of $f$, and the inverse of a closed-form function isn't always a closed-form function. But there is another issue, which is that (on one interpretation of the question) one can always pick $\delta$ to be a sufficiently slowly growing function of $\epsilon$. I think the OP wants to rule out this sort of thing but the question currently doesn't seem to be clearly phrased enough to rule it out.